# Cannot discover peers - Wifi Direct-

Tags: java, android, wifi-direct, wifip2p

I want to have a connection between two android devices on the same local network and exchange data between them through my android app.
I used Wifi Direct Api with Broadcast receiver approach in order to get into that purpose, but for some reason the discoverPeers method does not get triggered.

This is the code for my MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static MainActivity instance;

Button btnOnOff, btnDiscover, btnSend;
ListView listView;
TextView read_msg_box, connection_status;
EditText writeMessage;

WifiManager wifiManager;
WifiP2pManager mManager;
WifiP2pManager.Channel mChannel;

BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;
IntentFilter mIntentFilter;

List<WifiP2pDevice> peers = new ArrayList<WifiP2pDevice>();
String[] deviceNameArray;
WifiP2pDevice[] deviceArray;

WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener peerListListener = new WifiP2pManager.PeerListListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPeersAvailable(WifiP2pDeviceList peerList) {
        if (!peerList.getDeviceList().equals(peers)) {
            peers.clear();
            peers.addAll(peerList.getDeviceList());

            deviceNameArray = new String[peerList.getDeviceList().size()];
            deviceArray = new WifiP2pDevice[peerList.getDeviceList().size()];

            int index = 0;
            for (WifiP2pDevice device : peerList.getDeviceList()) {
                deviceNameArray[index] = device.deviceName;
                deviceArray[index] = device;
                index++;
            }

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, deviceNameArray);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        if (peers.size() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No device Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initialWork();
    exqListener();
}
public static MainActivity getInstance() {
    return instance;
}


private void exqListener() {
    btnOnOff.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled() == true) {
                wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
                btnOnOff.setText("Set To OFF ");
            } else {
                wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
                btnOnOff.setText("Set To ON");
            }
        }
    });

    btnDiscover.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            mManager.discoverPeers(mChannel, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    connection_status.setText("Discovery Started");
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(int reason) {
                    connection_status.setText("Discovery Starting Failed");
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

private void initialWork() {
    btnOnOff = (Button) findViewById(R.id.onOff);
    btnDiscover = (Button) findViewById(R.id.discover);
    btnSend = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
    read_msg_box = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.readMsg);
    connection_status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.connectionStatus);
    writeMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.writeMsg);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.peerListView);

    wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    mManager = (WifiP2pManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);
    mChannel = mManager.initialize(this, getMainLooper(), null);

    mReceiver = new WifiDirectBroadcastReceiver(mManager, mChannel, this);
    mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();

    mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
    mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
    mIntentFilter.addAction(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION);
}




@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, mIntentFilter);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}
```

}

And this is the one of the WifiDirectBroadcatReceiver:

```
public class WifiDirectBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
private WifiP2pManager mManager;
private WifiP2pManager.Channel mChannel;
private AppCompatActivity mActivity;

public WifiDirectBroadcastReceiver(WifiP2pManager mManager, WifiP2pManager.Channel mChannel, AppCompatActivity mActivity) {
    this.mManager = mManager;
    this.mChannel = mChannel;
    this.mActivity = mActivity;
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        int state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, -1);
        if (state == WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Wifi is ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Wifi is OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Dkhal hnaya bro", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (mManager != null) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }

            mManager.requestPeers(mChannel, MainActivity.getInstance().peerListListener);

            }
    } else if(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        // Do something
    } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

}

And this the permissions in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

According to the code, there is a textView that should change its text once I press on the button btnDiscover, but when I do, nothing happens.

Knowing that I was turning my location service on before running the app, what would the error be ?

Every other approach to tackle the situation will be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Starting Android 11, certain permissions have to be [requested during runtime](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#one-time), regardless of what's defined in your manifest. As the comments in your code point out, you should use `requestPermissions` to do so in your MainActivity and (optionally) react to the outcome using `onRequestPermissionsResult`.